# Drupal email field

Tags: email, drupal-7, drupal-fields

How can I lock the default e-mail field (make it read only), so that users will not be able to change their e-mail addresses after registering.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your template.php, there is an elaborate solution here: http://drupal.org/node/1241204#comment-7057244

*The following code was created by Isabug at the previous link:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mytheme_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $roles = $user->roles;
  if(in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
    return;
  }
  $form['account']['mail']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

You can disable email field using jquery,

Set the disabled attribute.

```
$("yourIdorClassforemailfield").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To enable again

```
$("yourIdorClassforemailfield").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Note: This will (obviusly) not work for users who disabled javascript in their browser.

Comment: I don't think users 'll do that